# How to redirect servlet post request another server url with post method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a request parameter and want to hit another server url by post method how to redirect from my servlet

responce.sendRedirect()     support get method

Answer (score -1):

create Html form in your servlet using PrintWriter Object and send the form action using Post method.
try this!!!

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

then write your html code inside out.println()

Comment: On form submit my base url appends at starting.          For example:  http://localhost:8080/myapplication/http://google. com